# noUiSlider change range on slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

could you help me with noUIslider?

I have simple slider:

```
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: 250,
        range: { min: 100, max: 500 },
        tooltips: [ wNumb({ decimals: 0 }) ],
        pips: {
        mode: 'range',
        behaviour: 'tap',
        density: 5,
        },
    });
```

When I'm sliding (holding left clickmouse):

```
var holdSlider;
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    holdSlider = setInterval(function(){

        // how to implement change RANGE of slider
        // e.g.: range: { min: 400, max: 1000 }

    }, 10);
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    if (holdSlider) clearInterval(holdSlider)
});
```

Can I change dynamically range when I'm sliding to righ or left in slider without let left clickmouse?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although the slider will glitch a little, it's not exactly designed to change mid-slide.

Instead of using `setInterval` and document-wide event listeners, you can use the event listeners provided by the noUiSlider library itself.

[Documentation on events](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/)

[Documentation on updating options](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-update)

```js
var sliderEl = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(sliderEl, {
    start: 250,
    range: { min: 100, max: 500 },
    tooltips: [ wNumb({ decimals: 0 }) ],
    pips: {
        mode: 'range',
        behaviour: 'tap',
        density: 5,
    },
});

sliderEl.noUiSlider.on('slide', function() {
    // As per documentation, the callback function is called in the context
    // of the slider object, so 'this' can be used to call API methods
    this.updateOptions({
     range: {
            'min': 400,
            'max': 1000
        }
    });
});

sliderEl.noUiSlider.on('change', function() {
    this.updateOptions({
        range: {
            'min': 100,
            'max': 500
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.0.0/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.0.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wnumb/1.1.0/wNumb.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding: 50px 20px;">
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```